# Cycle Through Divs With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a class that contains a bunch of divs with attached ids.  With jQuery, I am attempting to cycle through these divs dynamically.

My HTML:

```
                <div id ="result">RESULT GOES HERE</div>

                <div class = "tplandesclist">
                    <div id="tplandesc1"><%= tplan.tplandesc %></div>
                    <div id="tplandesc2"><%= tplan.tplandesc2 %></div>
                    <div id="tplandesc3"><%= tplan.tplandesc3 %></div>
                    <div id="tplandesc4"><%= tplan.tplandesc4 %></div>
                    <div id="tplandesc5"><%= tplan.tplandesc5 %></div>
                    <div id="tplandesc6"><%= tplan.tplandesc6 %></div>
                    <div id="tplandesc7"><%= tplan.tplandesc7 %></div>
                    <div id="tplandesc8"><%= tplan.tplandesc8 %></div>
                </div>
```

My jQuery, which upon click, erases the html of the #result and attempts to append the next item underneath the parent div .tplandesclist.  However, I know there is something wrong with the way I'm trying to do this. I am attempting to do it by using the .next() method instead of implementing some sort of counter and rewriting the algorithm completely.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".arrow").click(function(){

     $("#result").html(' ');
     $("#result").append().find(".tplandesclist")).next()

      });
     });
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $list = $(".tplandesclist > div");
    $(".arrow").click(function(){
        var $next = $list.filter(".current").removeClass('current').next();
        if(!$next.length){
            $next = $list.first()
        }

        $next.addClass('current')
        $("#result").html('').append($next.clone());

    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hn8uE/)

Comment: what does the ">" operator do in this line? Tell jQuery to look for divs within that class?  var $list = $(".tplandesclist > div");

Comment: also, what is the class .current, it looks like your'e filtering on it on the click, but none are initially assigned current?